# OpenCV: reading image file to passed Mat object inside function doesn't affect it globally

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to read a image file inside function and display it outside, but passed Mat object outside the function is blank. Inside it can be displayed without problems.

```
bool openFile(Mat image, string *imageName)
{
    image = imread(samples::findFile(*imageName, false, true), IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(image.empty())
    {
        cout <<  "File cannot be opened!" << endl ;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    String imageName("test.jpg");

    if( openFile(image, &imageName) ) return -1;

    namedWindow("Output", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Output", image);

    return 0;
}
```

How should I pass Mat object into function (I know that passing Mat objects only passes header of the object, not whole data matrix)?

Comment: Pass it by reference.

Comment: @rafix07 Yeah, but OP is assigning it the result of `imread`, which makes `image` in `openFile` refer to the new buffer, while the `image` in `main` is still just default-initialized. Same would happen if it was just a `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: @rafix07 Even if the assignment was replaced with an explicit copy, it would still only work if `image` was already the correct shape and datatype. Otherwise a reallocation would be required (which is like creating a new instance with single reference).